Cisco VoIP phone unable to receive calls
I recently got a used Cisco CP-7821 phone and I'm trying to set it up for calls using a number from a local SIP provider. So far I've managed to get it to register and I can make outgoing calls, e.g. from 7821 to my smartphone number, voice is heard both ways. Unfortunately I can't get incoming calls to work. When I try to call 7821 the phone starts ringing, it displays my other dialing number correctly, but upon pickup no connection is created, there is no voice or any sound signal in both devices. My dialing phone detects picking up and displays usual call timer etc. but 7821 doesn't seem to notice the call. When 7821 is ringing I can also press Decline on it and it will result in normal "phone busy" response on my dialing phone.
I load phone configuration using TFTP, most of it is based on information found here: https://usecallmanager.nz/sepmac-cnf-xml.html. Currently I'm using firmware version sip78xx.14-2-1-0401-61. My full config below, I only removed personal information:
<device>
    <fullConfig>true</fullConfig>
    <deviceProtocol>SIP</deviceProtocol>
    <ipAddressMode>0</ipAddressMode>
    <devicePool>
        <dateTimeSetting>
            <dateTemplate>D/M/Y</dateTemplate>
            <timeZone>Central Europe Standard/Daylight Time</timeZone>
            <ntps>
                <ntp priority="0">
                    <name>194.146.251.100</name>
                    <ntpMode>unicast</ntpMode>
                </ntp>
            </ntps>
        </dateTimeSetting>
        <callManagerGroup>
            <members>
                <member priority="0">
                    <callManager>
                        <ports>
                            <sipPort>5060</sipPort>
                        </ports>
                        <processNodeName>sip.halonet.pl</processNodeName>
                    </callManager>
                </member>
            </members>
        </callManagerGroup>
    </devicePool>
    <sipProfile>
        <sipProxies>
            <registerWithProxy>true</registerWithProxy>
        </sipProxies>
        <sipCallFeatures>
            <cnfJoinEnabled>false</cnfJoinEnabled>
            <localCfwdEnable>false</localCfwdEnable>
            <callForwardURI></callForwardURI>
            <callPickupURI></callPickupURI>
            <callPickupGroupURI></callPickupGroupURI>
            <meetMeServiceURI></meetMeServiceURI>
            <callHoldRingback>0</callHoldRingback>
            <semiAttendedTransfer>false</semiAttendedTransfer>
            <anonymousCallBlock>0</anonymousCallBlock>
            <callerIdBlocking>0</callerIdBlocking>
            <dndControl>1</dndControl>
            <dndCallAlert>1</dndCallAlert>
            <remoteCcEnable>true</remoteCcEnable>
        </sipCallFeatures>
        <sipStack>
            <timerRegisterExpires>3600</timerRegisterExpires>
            <timerRegisterDelta>5</timerRegisterDelta>
            <timerInviteExpires>180</timerInviteExpires>
            <timerKeepAliveExpires>3600</timerKeepAliveExpires>
            <timerSubscribeExpires>3600</timerSubscribeExpires>
            <timerSubscribeDelta>5</timerSubscribeDelta>
            <timerT1>500</timerT1>
            <timerT2>4000</timerT2>
            <remotePartyID>true</remotePartyID>
        </sipStack>
        <sipLines>
            <line button="1" lineIndex="1">
                <featureID>9</featureID>
                <featureLabel>MY NAME</featureLabel>
                <contact>200</contact>
                <speedDialNumber></speedDialNumber>
                <proxy>USECALLMANAGER</proxy>
                <port>5060</port>
                <voipControlPort>5060</voipControlPort>
                <name>MY SIP LOGIN</name>
                <displayName>MY NAME</displayName>
                <autoAnswer>
                    <autoAnswerEnabled>0</autoAnswerEnabled>
                </autoAnswer>
                <callWaiting>0</callWaiting>
                <authName>MY SIP LOGIN</authName>
                <authPassword>MY SIP PASSWORD</authPassword>
                <sharedLine>false</sharedLine>
                <messagesNumber></messagesNumber>
                <messageWaitingLampPolicy>3</messageWaitingLampPolicy>
                <ringSettingActive>5</ringSettingActive>
                <forwardCallInfoDisplay>
                    <callerName>true</callerName>
                    <callerNumber>true</callerNumber>
                    <redirectedNumber>true</redirectedNumber>
                    <dialedNumber>true</dialedNumber>
                </forwardCallInfoDisplay>
                <maxNumCalls>1</maxNumCalls>
                <busyTrigger>1</busyTrigger>
            </line>
            <line button="2">
                <featureID>2</featureID>
                <featureLabel>MY OTHER PHONE FOR DIAL TESTING</featureLabel>
                <speedDialNumber>MY OTHER PHONE FOR DIAL TESTING</speedDialNumber>
            </line>
        </sipLines>
        <enableVad>false</enableVad>
        <preferredCodec>none</preferredCodec>
        <dialTemplate>dialplan.xml</dialTemplate>
        <softKeyControl>1</softKeyControl>
        <softKeyFile>softkey1.xml</softKeyFile>
        <kpml>0</kpml>
        <phoneLabel>TEST 16</phoneLabel>
        <stutterMsgWaiting>2</stutterMsgWaiting>
        <disableLocalSpeedDialConfig>true</disableLocalSpeedDialConfig>
        <dscpForAudio>184</dscpForAudio>
        <dscpVideo>136</dscpVideo>
        <startMediaPort>10000</startMediaPort>
        <stopMediaPort>20000</stopMediaPort>
    </sipProfile>
    <commonProfile>
        <phonePassword></phonePassword>
        <callLogBlfEnabled>3</callLogBlfEnabled>
    </commonProfile>
    <featurePolicyFile>featurePolicy1.xml</featurePolicyFile>
    <loadInformation>sip78xx.14-2-1-0401-61</loadInformation>
    <vendorConfig>
        <cucmGSMHandoffPreference>0</cucmGSMHandoffPreference>
        <sshAccess>0</sshAccess>
        <webAccess>0</webAccess>
        <webProtocol>0</webProtocol>
    </vendorConfig>
    <commonConfig>
        <videoCapability>0</videoCapability>
        <ciscoCamera>0</ciscoCamera>
    </commonConfig>
    <sshUserId>sshuser123</sshUserId>
    <sshPassword>cisco</sshPassword>
    <userId></userId>
    <versionStamp>0003330027034305</versionStamp>
    <userLocale>
        <name>SIP_English_United_States</name>
        <langCode>en_US</langCode>
    </userLocale>
    <networkLocale>SIP_United_States</networkLocale>
    <networkLocaleInfo>
        <name>United_States</name>
    </networkLocaleInfo>
    <authenticationURL></authenticationURL>
    <directoryURL></directoryURL>
    <servicesURL></servicesURL>
    <dscpForSCCPPhoneServices>0</dscpForSCCPPhoneServices>
    <dscpForCm2Dvce>96</dscpForCm2Dvce>
    <transportLayerProtocol>2</transportLayerProtocol>
    <telnetAccess>0</telnetAccess>
</device>

Phone has static IP configured in my router. I tried various options with the network itself, disabling firewall, placing phone in DMZ but nothing helps. I've also changed the router entirely twice now with no difference. I think my network is not a problem tho, because I can plug an analog phone through a noname VoIP gateway to the same router I'm using and it works fine both for calling and receiving, same SIP credentials used for a gateway of course.
I'd like to know if this is possible to do without creating a PBX or something? I want my system to be as simple as possible. Is there a problem with my config or maybe network related? Also I'm aware this device is supposed to be used with CUCM but I've seen people claim to have it working with 3rd party solutions as well. Getting a Yealink, Grandstream or similar dedicated SIP phone would also be easier, but at this point I'm more interested in solving a problem since it all seems to be close to working state. Thank you for any possible hints or solutions.

Somehow despite weeks of trial and error I found a solution one day after posting. I changed routers again, this time I'm using D-Link DIR-2150. While searching the web it was mostly recommended to disable SIP ALG, but on this router after enabling SIP ALG my phone just worked! My ISP provided Sagemcom doesn't even have this option so it slipped past my mind to check it more. For some time after that the phone also stopped working again as I assigned static IP to it, but some combination of using different address and power cycling both devices made it behave correctly.
I'll leave this post up, hopefully it'll provide some help to anyone else struggling with similar problems. Also feel free to contact me if needed.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: Accept Your Own Answers.
